# how to destructure exact values from a unknown array of objects to always go in their specific variables else undefined, but with help of only 1 loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

how to destructure exact values from a unknown array of objects to always go in their specific variables else undefined, but with help of only 1 loop (find ,filter , etc...)

```
 const [tableEdit,tableDelete] = useMemo(() => {
    return panelPermissionsPerWidget?.filter(ele => ele.type === 'table_edit' || ele.type === 
    'table_delete');
 }, [panelPermissionsPerWidget]);
```

i want index with ele.type===table_edit to only  go in tableEdit ,similar with tableDelete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would pre-populate an array of undefined, loop the list and put into the array 0 & 1 as needed..

eg.

```
const [tableEdit,tableDelete] = useMemo(() => {
   const ret = [undefined, undefined];
   if (panelPermissionsPerWidget) {
     for (const ele of panelPermissionsPerWidget) {
       if (ele.type === 'table_edit') ret[0] = ele
       else if (ele.type === 'table_delete') ret[1] = ele;
     }
   }
   return ret;
 }, [panelPermissionsPerWidget]);
```

Instead of array destructor syntax, if you want to destructor different types, then you would be better using object destructoring.

eg.

```
const {tableEdit,tableDelete} = useMemo(() => {
   const ret = {};
   if (panelPermissionsPerWidget) {
     for (const ele of panelPermissionsPerWidget) {
       if (ele.type === 'table_edit') ret.tableEdit = ele
       else if (ele.type === 'table_delete') ret.tableDelete = ele;
     }
   }
   return ret;
}, [panelPermissionsPerWidget]);
```

Comment: Hi, but it is not sure that there will be only two items in the array ,there could be more or none too

Comment: @Rt7Rt7 this will still work for more elements or none elements

Comment: @Rt7Rt7  You might want to destructor from an object instead, I'll knock up an object version.

Comment: hmm yes it'll  work i guess , ill try